# How to call a cloud function from your flutter app without await and with parameters

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a huge function in my Flutter app, and every time I call it, it takes a long time to run. I want to rewrite it as a google cloud function and call it in my app in order to minimize the loading time.
Here is the way I call my backend function.

the title is a string value,
the arrayRanges is an array of arrays

```
     try {
      final result = FirebaseFunctions.instance
          .httpsCallable('generatingAppointments')
          .call(
        {
          'title': daysOfHelp[k].title,
          'arrayRanges': ArrayOfAllTheDayRanges,
        },
      );
      print("generatingAppointments No error");
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
      print("generatingAppointments error");
      print(error.code);
      print(error.details);
      print(error.message);
    }
```

and after this my UI navigate to another page in my app immediately

and this is a simple code in the backend to test if I call the backend function correctly

```
   exports.generatingAppointments = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    functions.logger.info("generatingAppointments Is running");
    console.log('New Message written');
  });
```

but the problem is I don't see any of the print I wrote in the backend in my logs.

Note: I don't need the result to return to my app, I will store it in the database and use it later.

EDIT:
when I removed ArrayOfAllTheDayRanges parameter the logs shows in my consol, but I don't know why this parameter cause a problem
ArrayOfAllTheDayRanges is an array of arrays

Comment: How and where are you checking the print statement(console.log and functions.logger.info) you used in the backend?

Comment: Using the Google Cloud Console via the link in the firebase dashbord

Comment: Do you see other logs that indicate that the function has been called successfully?

Comment: No, and I think the problem from the parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my problem was in sending ArrayOfAllTheDayRanges which is an array of arrays (2-dimensional array). so when I remove it every thing went will

Answer (score 1):

To be able to see the logs when you use console.log, you need to `require` the below dependencies

**For console.log**

```
require("firebase-functions/logger/compat");
```

e.g `console.log(username)`

**For logger.log**

```
const { warn } = require("firebase-functions/logger");
```

e.g.

```
logger.log() commands have the INFO log level.

logger.info() commands have the INFO log level.

logger.warn() commands have the WARNING log level.

logger.error() commands have the ERROR log level.
```

**For functions.logger.log**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
```

e.g.

```
functions.logger.log("Hello");
```